# Overwrite static variable in fuelphp

Tags: php, static, fuelphp

I have a sample code in php

```
class First {
    public static $name;    
    public static function getName() {
       return static::$name;
    }
}

class Second extends First {
    public static $name = 'second';
}

echo Second::getName();  // print 'second'
```

But when I write it into fuelphp:

File 1:

```
namespace Model;
use \DB;

class ModelMain extends \Model {
    public static $table_name;

    public static function getName() {
        return self::$table_name;
    }
}
```

File 2

```
class Post extends \Model\ModelMain {
    public static $table_name = "post";
}
```

When I call

```
Post::getName() // Print null
```

I expected it will print post. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Try replacing `return self::$table_name;` with `return static::$table_name;`

Comment: This is due to lack of polymorphic behavior in static methods.

Comment: @hoangvu68, Didn't you there was already an answer here before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `null` since the `$table_name` is not assigned , Instead you should add `return static::$table_name;` inside the `getName()` of the `ModelMain` class to enable the `Late Static Binding` , so it does display`post` as output.

Late Static Binding...

```
<?php

namespace Model;
use \DB;

class ModelMain extends \Model  {
    public static $table_name;

    public static function getName() {
        return static::$table_name; //<--- Add static here to introduce LSB
    }
}


class Post extends \Model\ModelMain {
    public static $table_name = "post";
}


echo Post::getName();
```

Comment: Late Static Binding !